# React Native - Getting an undefined returned value error from a built-in component

Tags: react-native, expo

Error:Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string .... but got: undefined.

The code in question is:

````
```
DefectDetails = (props) => {
   if (props.currentStep != 2) {

    return null;
    }

return (
<View>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Defect Details</Text>
    <Text>Record the return state of the asset</Text>
    <Picker
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({returnState:itemValue})}
    >
        <Picker.item value="null" label="Select return functionality"/>
        <Picker.item value="0" label="Working"/>
        <Picker.item value="1"label="Unservicable (red)"/>
        <Picker.item value="2" label="Requires Attention (amber)"/>
    </Picker>

    <this.DefectDescription returnState={this.state.returnState}/>        

</View>

)
}

DefectDescription = (props) => {
const returnState=this.props.returnState
if (returnState=="1"|returnState=="2") {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Describe issue</Text>
        <TextInput/>
    </View>
    ) }
return null;
}
````

When I replace `<this.DefectDescription/>` with the expected return value of DefectDescription it all works fine.
Base code was generated via Expo and only App.js has been modified.

The full code is :

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  CheckBox,
  Input,
  Picker
} from 'react-native';
import * as assetData from './assets/assetData.json';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          asset_id: "TST-001-WD",
          currentStep: 1,
          assetRecord:assetData,
          hasPermission: null,
          setHasPermission: null,
          scanned: false,
          setScanned: false,
          returnState:"null",
          hasError: false,
        }
       console.log(this.state.assetRecord);
    }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
    }

  // Test current step with ternary
  // _next and _previous functions will be called on button click
    _next = () => {
      let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
      // If the current step is 1 or 2, then add one on "next" button click
      currentStep = currentStep >= 5? 6: currentStep + 1;
      this.setState({
        currentStep: currentStep
      });
    }

    _prev = () => {
      let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
      // If the current step is 2 or 3, then subtract one on "previous" button click
      currentStep = currentStep <= 1? 1: currentStep - 1;
      this.setState({
        currentStep: currentStep,
      });
    }

    previousButton() {
      let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
      if(currentStep !==1){
        return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.button}
         onPress={this._prev}
        >
        <Text>Previous</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
      return null;
    }

    nextButton(){
      let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
      if(currentStep <2){
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._next}
            >
                <Text>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
      return null;
    }



AssetDetails = (props) => {
    if (props.currentStep != 1) {

        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Asset Details</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Asset Id</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.asset_id}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this.keyboardEntry}
                >
                    <Text>Keyboard</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Manufacturer</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.assetRecord.Manufacturer_name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Product</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.assetRecord.Asset_description}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Loan status</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.assetRecord.loan_status}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Asset status</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.assetRecord.Asset_Status_name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>RAG Status</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.assetRecord.ragStatus}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

    )
}


DefectDetails = (props) => {
    if (props.currentStep != 2) {

        return null;
    }

    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Defect Details</Text>
        <Text>Record the return state of the asset</Text>
        <Picker
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({returnState:itemValue})}
        >
            <Picker.item value="null" label="Select return functionality"/>
            <Picker.item value="0" label="Working"/>
            <Picker.item value="1"label="Unservicable (red)"/>
            <Picker.item value="2" label="Requires Attention (amber)"/>
        </Picker>

        <this.DefectDescription returnState={this.state.returnState}/>        

    </View>

    )
}

DefectDescription = (props) => {
    const returnState=this.props.returnState
    if (returnState=="1"|returnState=="2") {
        return (
        <View>
            <Text>Describe issue</Text>
            <TextInput/>
        </View>
        ) }
    return null;

}


 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
            <this.AssetDetails
                currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
            />


            <this.DefectDetails
                currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
            />


        </View>

        <View       style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
        {this.previousButton()}
        {this.nextButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  title: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  label:{
    paddingRight: 10,    
  },
  row:{
    paddingRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }
})

export default App;
```

The assetData.json file is:

```
{
    "Asset_id": "23",
    "Manufacturer_id": "44",
    "Asset_Category_id": "32",
    "Location_id": "7",
    "Asset_Status_id": "4",
    "Acquired_date": "2014-09-01",
    "Disposal_date": "",
    "External_Asset_id": "VEH-001-WD",
    "Asset_description": "Transit tipper",
    "Comment": "Donated - second hand",
    "Last_serviced": "2017-04-11",
    "Owner_id": "1",
    "Serial_no": "",
    "Manufacturer_name": "Ford",
    "Asset_Category_name": "Vehicle",
    "Location_name": "Western Depot",
    "Recording": "Miles",
    "derived_status": "3",
    "RAGColour": "LightGreen",
    "loan_status": "Checked out",
    "last_miles_hours": "137",
    "last_checklist": [{
        "faultData": "true",
        "lights": "true",
        "tyres": "true"
    }],
    "last_return_time": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "category_list": null,
    "Asset_Status_name": "Available subject to RAG",
    "faultList": [{
        "Asset_Defect_id": "7",
        "status_id": "3",
        "statusText": "Accepted (No action needed)",
        "Fault_description": "Cracked windscreen"
    }, {
        "Asset_Defect_id": "13",
        "status_id": "3",
        "statusText": "Accepted (No action needed)",
        "Fault_description": "The sticker has fallen off the tailgate"
    }, {
        "Asset_Defect_id": "29",
        "status_id": "3",
        "statusText": "Accepted (No action needed)",
        "Fault_description": "Bonnet catch has fallen off"
    }],
    "checkList": [{
        "checklist_item_id": "3",
        "checklist_item_longtext": "Light check includes head lights, stop lights and indicators",
        "checklist_item_title": "Lights",
        "checklist_item_code": "lights",
        "preChecked": ""
    }, {
        "checklist_item_id": "2",
        "checklist_item_longtext": "Tyres must be checked for wear and pressure",
        "checklist_item_title": "Tyres",
        "checklist_item_code": "tyres",
        "preChecked": ""
    }]
}
```

I am very much a new developer with this tool set and It probably something very simple, but I've been puzzling over this for two days now

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<DefectDescription />` not `<this.DefectDescription/>`

Comment: If still not works share a snack with me and I will fix it.

Comment: It is in the same class. Taking 'this' out leads to an unfound variable error.

Comment: I appreciate your offer of help, but I'm afraid I have no idea how to share a snack.

Comment: Write on google "create expo snack" open expo create a snack, add your same code there and share with me the url of that snack.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this is th one you need: https://snack.expo.io/@vincehall/asset-loan

Comment: yup this is what is want, I ran your snack but not been able to generate the error, Can you please tell me how can I produce an error that you are facing.

Comment: So, I click on the 'Next' button and the error comes up. From Snack I had to follow the link to come up with the real error message. On Expo the error was displayed without following a link.

Comment: Have  a look at this https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/asset-loan
I am not been able to produce the error when I click next.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can put screen dumps up here, but it is certainly happening for me in your snack too. I use the web interface option, the app screen is displayed on the right hand side of the browser showing the details of the ford tipper truck. I click on the next button at the bottom of the app and the red panel is displayed with the error.

Comment: share with me your skype.